# Snowflake error handling using SQL language in stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My stored procedure is returning table as a result. I am trying get logic if select statement fail here.

If it fails, I am calling another stored procedure which is inserting status in table  and returning table as a NULL.

But I'm getting an error

> Uncaught exception of type EXPRESSION_ERROR", unknown function ROWCOUNT"

Select statement:

```
res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_query);

IF(ROW_COUNT() = 0) THEN
    proc_status := 'FAILED';

    error_msg := GET_STACK_TRACE();

    sql_command_audit := 'CALL EODS_'||ENV||'.DATA.'||'sp_batch_end'||'('''||domain_area||''','''||proc_name||''','''||proc_status||''','''||error_msg||''','''||0||''','''||0||''');';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_command_audit;

    RETURN TABLE (SELECT NULL::NUMBER as Ac ,NULL::VARCHAR as IC);

END IF;
```

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be a variable called ROWCOUNT in your code so either there’s a typo, it’s in part of your SP code that you haven’t supplied or the error is coming from the second SP that you are calling. In either case, there’s not enough information here to help you